# laravel pusher socket is null

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am trying to use laravel broadcast with pusher but my socket is showing null.

my env file

```
  BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
  CACHE_DRIVER=file
  QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
  SESSION_DRIVER=file
  SESSION_LIFETIME=120

  PUSHER_APP_ID=12345
  PUSHER_APP_KEY=ABCDEFG
  PUSHER_APP_SECRET=HKLMNOP
  PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
  PUSHER_APP_HOST=127.0.0.1
  MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
  MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Answer (score 0):

in your broadcasting.php did you set 'options' => [ 'cluster' => '', 'encrypted' => true ], your broadcasting.php should look like below

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'ap2',
                'encrypted' => true
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: I am using it on my localhost. not on https live server. I was thing encrypted is for https url